# Inspecting custom annotations on Java class

Tags: java, annotations

I am trying to parse some custom annotations on a few of the classes in my application.

When I call:

```
myAnnotatedClass.getAnnotation(CustomAnnotation.class);
```

Null is returned.

When I manually step through the annotations on the class, I can see that the annotation that I am interested in is there:

```
Annotation[] presentAnnotations = myAnnotatedClass.getAnnotations();
for(Annotation a : presentAnnotations) {
   System.out.println("annotation: " + a);
   System.out.println("type: " + a.annotationType());
}
```

This is the output:

```
annotation: @com.mycompany.client.annotations.CustomAnnotation(someAttributue=[.....])
type: interface com.mycompany.client.annotations.CustomAnnotation
```

I can't quite figure out why the call to `getAnnotation()` is returning null.

Comment: Are you sure that you've imported the correct `CustomAnnotation` for the first example? If so, I'm pretty sure this should work. If it shows up in the second example, it's correctly annotated with `Retention.RUNTIME`, so it should be available for a `getAnnotation` call too. You could check with `CustomAnnotation::class == a.annotationType()`.

Comment: Try adding this on Annotation @Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)

Comment: @Shekhar That is doubly incorrect. [A] clearly not the problem (given that it does show up with `.getAnnotations()` and [B] wouldn't even work (you want `RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME`).

Comment: Another possible stumbling stone that could cause issues like this is if the `CustomAnnotation` is loaded by more than one classloader. That would lead to two classes with the exact same name in the JVM that would still be considered to be distinct. Try printing `a.annotationType().getClassLoader()` and `CustomAnnotation.class.getClassLoader()`.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy explanation and a much more complex one.

### The easy explanation

You messed up. You have 2 different types that are both called `CustomAnnotation` (in different packages), and you are confusing the two.

You might want to confirm this isn't the mistake you made. One easy way to do that is to compare FQNs:

```
Annotation[] presentAnnotations = myAnnotatedClass.getAnnotations();
for(Annotation a : presentAnnotations) {
   System.out.println("annotation: " + a);
   System.out.println("type: " + a.annotationType());
   System.out.println("Sanity check: " + 
  CustomAnnotation.class.getName().equals(a.annotationType());
}
```

This *should* print at least one `Sanity check: true`. If it doesn't - stop reading here (it's not the 'complicated explanation').

### The complicated explanation

In java, classes are singletons: It is not possible for more than one instance of `java.lang.Class` representing your class to exist, and they are only ever loaded once.

However.

The 'id' of a class, the very nature of it, is actually a tuple of the class definition *and the class loader that truly loads it by invoking `defineClass` and passing the bytecode to that native method*.

ClassLoaders are both extensible (you can make your own, and they can do whatever they want, notably including reloading an already loaded class and **therefore creating two completely unrelated, different classes which nevertheless have exactly the same Fully Qualified Name!**), and varied (any given JVM can have many classloaders simultaneously).

This is very relevant - even if you think this doesn't apply ("I'm not making any classloaders!"), java *itself* uses classloaders. For your main app (`main` and all that follows from there), java uses the simple, obvious classloader: There is only one, and it loads classes off of the classpath as one would expect. **But**, agents, **and annotation processors**, use separate loaders for various things.

Hence, if the easy explanation has been excluded, this is the next most likely explanation: Whatever code is running `.getAnnotation(CustomAnnotation.class)` isn't finding your annotation because the annotation that is present is a completely different type. Also named the exact same thing as `CustomAnnotation`, but, loaded by a different loader and therefore not considered the same by the system.

There are no easy fixes for that. You can't ask java to take an instance of `CustomAnnotation-loaded-by-loaderA` and make it 'fit' `CustomAnnotation-loaded-by-loaderB`. That's because loaderA and loaderB might well have loaded completely different versions of it (one of the advantages of java's loader system is that you can use it to load 2 conflicting, different versions of the exact same library in the same JVM. From there it is obvious that the downside is that such loads are utterly incompatible with each other. They'd have to be or that cannot possibly be universally possible).

One fix is to ensure that `CustomAnnotation` is only ever loaded once (classloaders are hierarchical: By default they ask their parent loader to laod it, and if it loads it, that it just passes that on, which means that parent loader is the official loader. Have 2 separate ClassLoaders with the same parent, if they both delegate the loading of `java.lang.String` to the parent, then code loaded by loaderA can send strings to loaderB without issue. But, if loaderA and/or loaderB explicitly opts out of this delegation system and loads it itself, we have 2 classes, completely separate, both called `java.lang.String`, and which aren't compatible with each other).

Another is to 'deal' with the `CustomAnnotation` from the other universe. Use `.getAnnotations()`, find the right annotation, and use reflection to read its data. You will not be able to cast it, though! It has to *ALL* be stringly typed (that's not a typo - 'stringly typed', as in, it's all checked and called with string literals). Yes, you can write:

```
com.foo.Bar bar = (com.foo.Bar) someObject;
```

and get a `ClassCastException` saying: `"Cannot cast object of type com.foo.Bar to com.foo.Bar"` which seems like an impossible and very silly error, but it's what you get when you cross the streams and have an object of type `Bar-by-loaderB` and try to run that cast expression in code loaded by a loader whose resolution of type `com.foo.Bar` ends up at `Bar-by-loaderA`. Hence, why this:

```
Annotation[] presentAnnotations = myAnnotatedClass.getAnnotations();
for(Annotation a : presentAnnotations) {
   System.out.println("annotation: " + a);
   System.out.println("type: " + a.annotationType());
   if (a instanceof CustomAnnotation) { ... }
}
```

is not going to work even if the `type:`  sysout line prints precisely the name of your custom annotation type, nor will `CustomAnnotation ca = (CustomAnnotation) a;`, for the same reason.

Comment: And, by the way, you can not have two classes named `java.lang.String`; custom class loaders are not allowed to create classes whose qualified name starts with `java.`.

Comment: In older versions of java I'm pretty sure you could, but, I admit, that was a poor choice of example. I will fix the problem with `a.annotationType() instanceof`.

Comment: [Java 1.3’s API documentation](https://javaalmanac.io/jdk/1.3/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass(java.lang.String,%20byte[],%20int,%20int,%20java.security.ProtectionDomain)) is the first mentioning explicitly that attempts to define a class starting with `java.` will throw an exception but that doesn’t mean that such an attempt would have succeeded in older versions.